# Where in Golarion do ice gnomes (Barbegazi) come from?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races, golarion

I want to play an [ice gnome (Barbegazi)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/barbegazi-ice-gnome) in our new adventure path but I cannot find anything about where in Golarion they come from. I've already searched heaps of wikis without success. Where are they native to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowhere.

As your link shows, ice gnomes are a creature from a third party monster book (Tome of Horrors).  Therefore that race isn't canonically native to Golarion.  You can of course propose a likely location of your choice for your campaign.